# Angular Test fails with expect not to be null when HTML uses ngIf condition

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a scenario where a variable y is generated from variable x. I am trying to write a test case for a variable y which is generated from a another declared variable x by using `split()` method. Also, I have a flag hasY whether to display the variable in HTML based on the value y. But, the test fails for some reason if I do not move the flag-hasY to the end of the method-func() initialization.

Below is my component and Test. I know the issue is with `hasY & y` variables. `If I have a default value for y variable or if I move hasY after y variable declaration the test was a pass.` But, I am not sure why is it failing if I declare the hasY before. Any idea??

HTML:

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>{{x}}</span>
  <span *ngIf="hasY">{{y}}</span>
</div>
```

AppComponent.ts ---> Here I am breaking the value using split()

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'test';
  public value: string = "3.50 cm";
  x: string = "";
  y: string = "";
  hasY: boolean = false;

  constructor(){}
  
  ngOnInit(){
  this.func()
  }

  func(){
    const values = this.value.split(" ");
    this.hasY =
    this.y !== undefined &&
    this.y !== null &&
    this.y.length > 0 &&
    this.y.trim().length > 0;
    
    if(values.length<2){return false;}

    this.x = values[0];
    this.y = values[1];
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

Test.ts --> Its a straight forward test. Not sure why it fails

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });;
  });


  it("test1", () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const j: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info > span:first-child"));
    expect(j).not.toBeNull();
    expect(j.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toEqual("3.50");

    const k: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info > span:nth-child(2)"));
    expect(k).not.toBeNull();
    expect(k.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toEqual("cm");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you have to move `this.hasY` after the initialization of `this.y`.

```
 ngOnInit(){
    const values = this.value.split(" ");
    this.hasY =
    this.y !== undefined &&
    this.y !== null &&
    this.y.length > 0 &&
    this.y.trim().length > 0;
    
    console.log(this.hasY); // you will see false because this.y = '' at this point


    this.x = values[0];
    this.y = values[1]; // if you move these two lines before this.hasY, the test will pass
    console.log(values);
  }
```

!!! Edit !!!
To make your test pass, just make `hasY` to true.

```
  it("test1", () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const j: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info > span:first-child"));
    expect(j).not.toBeNull();
    expect(j.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toEqual("3.50");
    
    // add these two lines
    component.hasY = true;
    // make the HTML update with fixture.detectChanges()
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const k: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".info > span:nth-child(2)"));
    expect(k).not.toBeNull();
    expect(k.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toEqual("cm");
  });
```

Comment: Well, your are right. But, in my case there might be a y value thrown from the API, if there is a value already for x and y the method ends and returns false, if the value doesn't exist then those values are assigned. Like: if(values.length<2){return false}